# How these matrices are working?

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence, matrix-multiplication

I am reading a article about pattern reconigation. I am not understanding how this 8 column coming from. and how its output is generating.

I tried to get the concept but i am not getting how first matrix have 8 column  ? and how its calculating output ?

> The network of figure 1 is trained to recognise the patterns T and H.
>   The associated patterns are all black and all white respectively as
>   shown below.
>   If we represent black squares with 0 and white squares with 1 then the
>   truth tables for the 3 neurones after generalisation are;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCZs7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each table represents one line of you image.

Each **column**(Xij) of your table represents possible combinations of those pixels in one line(of your input image) and **OUT** represents if those combinations evaluate to true or false.

There are 8 columns because there are 8 possibilities of combining 3 values of 1 and 0 (2 at the power of 3).

I think it's easier if you look at those tables on vertical(transpose).

Comment: First of all thank you for reply sir. Ok i got it that why there are 8 column . But one confusion is still there is how output are generating ? Like if they are following "AND" , "OR" or which gate rules ? or how "001 is 0" and 010 is 1" ?? In first table "001 is 0" and in second table "001 is 0/1" how ??